# dictionaries feature extraction Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, machine-learning, nlp, feature-extraction

I'm doing a text categorization experiment. For the feature extraction phase I'm trying to create a feature dictionary per document. For now, I have two features, Type token ratio and n-grams of the relative frequency of function words. When I print my instances, only the feature type token ratio is in the dictionary. This seems to be because an ill functioning `get_pos()`. It returns empty lists.
This is my code:

```
instances = []
labels = []
directory = "\\Users\OneDrive\Data"
for dname, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for fname in files:
        fpath = os.path.join(dname, fname)
        with open(fpath,'r') as f:
             text = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
             vector = {}

             #TTR
             lemmas = get_lemmas(text)
             unique_lem = set(lemmas)
             TTR = str(len(unique_lem) / len(lemmas))
             name = fname[:5]
             vector['TTR'+ '+' + name] = TTR


             #function word ngrams
             pos = get_pos(text)
             fw = []
             regex = re.compile(
               r'(LID)|(VNW)|(ADJ)|(TW)|(VZ)|(VG)|(BW)')
             for tag in pos:
                 if regex.search(tag):
                    fw.append(tag)
             for n in [1,2,3]:  
                 grams = ngrams(fw, n)
                 fdist = FreqDist(grams)
                 total = sum(c for g,c in fdist.items())
                 for gram, count in fdist.items():
                     vector['fw'+str(n)+'+'+' '+ name.join(gram)] = count/total

                 instances.append(vector)
                 labels.append(fname[:1])
print(instances)
```

And this is an example of a Dutch input file:[image: Example of Dutch input]

This is the code from the get_pos function, which I call from another script:

> ```
>    def get_pos(text):
>        row4=[]
>        pos = []
>        for row in text:
>            if not row:
>               continue  
>            else:
>               row4.append(row[4])
>               pos = [x.split('(')[0] for x in row4] # remove what's between the brackets
>         return pos
> ```

Can you help me find what's wrong with the get_pos function?

Comment: When debugging, I would focus on the output of `get_pos()`. If your regex doesn't match what you are given by `get_pos()`, then no features will be added.

Comment: @lenz Thank you for the tip, I'll check it out and let you know if that was the problem

Comment: @lenz, I guess the problem is indeed the get_pos function. It returns empty lists. I'll change my question.

Comment: Oh, I see what the problem is. When you call `get_lemmas(text)`, all contents of the file are consumed, so `get_pos(text)` has nothing left to iterate over. If you want to go through a file's content multiple times, you need to either `f.seek(0)` between the calls, or read the rows into a list in the beginning.

Comment: @lenz, I understand! Indeed this was the problem, it is solved now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `get_lemmas(text)`, all contents of the file are consumed, so `get_pos(text)` has nothing left to `iterate` over. If you want to go through a file's content multiple times, you need to either `f.seek(0)` between the calls, or read the rows into a `list` in the beginning and `iterate` over the `list` when needed.